# Adding a submit button to JupyterHub

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyterhub

I would like to use JupyterHub: https://jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html for the purpose of teaching.

But for me, it would be necessary to add to the Jupyter-Notebooks something like a submit button for my students. I don't want to add this submit-button directly into a cell. I would like to add it for example close to the navigation bar of my Jupyter-Notebook.

Does anybody have some experience with manipulating the Jupyter-Notebooks and can provide me with some information?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45105546/how-can-i-add-actions-to-the-tool-bar-in-the-dashboard-of-jupyter-notebook and https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extending/frontend_extensions.html

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I'm going to try to implement my requirement with this.